# Ctrl Key doesn't work

Tags: keyboard

I have an old keyboard. I like it because it is a mechanical one, just like the old ones. It is so old that it works with a port PS/2. 
Thus, some time ago, i decided to buy a conversor from this port to USB.

Well, now I have ubuntu 18.04 and this key and the windows key do not work at all.
i can't combine them (like most of the operations of ctrl+z or ctrl+c ..) and I can't go to the menu with the key because it does not work.

I want to add that there are two buttons (each side of the keyboard), but none of them works.

I heard that maybe is a question of mapping the keyboard, but i never did that, and not sure if maybe it is just broken or what.

Little help please!!

Comment: I too love my old model M keyboards (so old they don't have super keys).  I'd suggest you use `xev` to see if the keys are working, xev should show when you hold down CTRL, ALT or combinations (and later when you let them go, including combinations).  USB doesn't allow all the combinations PS2 recorded (ps2 allows any key combination, usb only allows a few special keys like ctrl, shift.. but super should still work in combination I'd expect)

Comment: So Guiverc. I search how to check my keys by using this XEV? I never used it before And no idea what I have to see...

Comment: open a terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and type `xev`  and you'll see every movement of your mouse (*if over the window*), and key-press (including letting go of keys) detected.  If you hit the key and it does nothing, the key isn't recognized by OS so it's hardware or a bios/uefi issue (& your OS can't fix with config as I doesn't see keypress).  If you get command-not-found error, `sudo apt install x11-utils` then run  (but I believe it's there for diagnostics by default)

Comment: So, in short, If I type "xev" ( i will check later, but i know it is installed by default) It will let me know if It is a software or hardware issue. If XEV detects it, software. If not, Hardware and I betta throw the keyboard.
then, if it is software? what shall I do?

Comment: `xev` & hit enter.  xev is the command that will *print contents of X events*  (so if mouse is over the window it is reported, otherwise keyboard... If you highlight another window it won't see keystrokes, but it's pretty easy to see response from any working keys...